# How is it possible for a moderator to decline a "should be closed" flag?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, moderators

While checking out my flag history, I just noticed that two of my flags for closure are **declined** (not just disputed):

[image: Two declined flags - one of them is "off-topic" and the other is "unclear what you're asking"]

How is this possible? Did a moderator decline them by clicking <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> in [Close Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close), or do such flags have a higher priority than what I think in the flag queue?

Comment: Relevant: [What causes a recommend closure flag to be marked disputed, versus helpful or declined?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253827/what-causes-a-recommend-closure-flag-to-be-marked-disputed-versus-helpful-or-de)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All closure flags are handled via the Close Vote review queue, even by ♦ moderators. On Stack Overflow, they usually don't take part in it, but in your second case, [one of them actually did](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/13331764).

The flags are declined because the result of the reviews was to leave the questions open and *all reviewers* either chose <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> or used a different close reason than you did. *Normally*, it takes three <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> votes, but in the case of your second question, a ♦ moderator's vote is binding and it immediately terminated the review.

<sub>Credits to [@animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333899/how-is-it-possible-for-a-moderator-to-decline-a-should-be-closed-flag/333901?noredirect=1#comment391665_333901) for pointing out a gap in my SO knowledge.</sub>

Comment: It doesn't have to be *all* reviewers. It's simply declined if the result of the review item ends up being Leave Open and the flag is still pending. It's helpful if at any point it gets closed or another user casts a close vote for the exact same reason. It cannot be marked as disputed via the Close Votes review. That only happens if there is a Triage review that ends up being Looks Ok.

Comment: @animuson thanks, but that's really confusing. If I would flag a question as 'Unclear' and it's closed as a duplicate, the flag is helpful, but if it fails by one vote (and stays open), it is declined? And it would really help if this is documented somewhere, but I'll try to update my post accordingly.

Comment: Not quite, if any user at any point casts a close vote for the same reason as you, it's instantly dismissed as helpful and the review doesn't matter anymore. So to be declined, you need both a) the review result to come out as Leave Open and b) no one to ever cast a close vote for the same reason you chose (on either the question or the review). It's actually a pretty stringent criteria for declining.

Comment: @animuson I would expect the flag to be declined also when it's closed and  all close voters used a reason different than the flagger.

Comment: It's hard to argue that should happen. Technically their flag did result in the parent action (the question getting closed) being completed, even if other users didn't agree with the reason they chose. Would be especially upsetting if a moderator came along and closed it with a different reason than all the flags or even existing close votes - I've done so many times myself.