# Off-topic flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258332/distributed-computing-in-c

It is an old question with good voting feedback, so I can see hesitance to close it. But my flag was declined, even though it seems to fit this selection:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

Was this a mistake by the flag reviewer or does the question actually meet the guidelines?

**Edit:** this is not a duplicate of [How is it possible for a moderator to decline a "should be closed" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333899) because, as yellowantphil points out, this question is asking why the flag was declined, not how.

Comment: Looks eerily similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128282) other one i can't get closed, only it's more recent.

Comment: I would seriously only flag new stuff and leave everything from the past alone.... too much drama.

Comment: I generally agree to leave the old stuff untouched, there are probably a bunch of hidden questions that would be now off-topic that have remained untouched for years.  If a question like that is bumped to the front page by a vote or new answer, I think then it would be acceptable to vote to close.  In your case, the question was bumped 4 days ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is it possible for a moderator to decline a "should be closed" flag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333899/how-is-it-possible-for-a-moderator-to-decline-a-should-be-closed-flag)

Comment: Who would vote to reopen that tool request???

Comment: For those meta-effectateers who are visiting to close the question... hey, don't forget to VTC the question linked in the comments! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257245/message-passing-concurrency-library-for-c/257312

Comment: @Will Done. Funny that one tried to close it as "belongs on Server Fault". I hope that was a mis-click.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Three people reviewed your flag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/13700007) and decided it didn't need to be closed.

Of course, now that you've brought it up here on meta, the question has collected several close votes and may end up being closed anyway.