# How many aged away flags are common?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags

I'm doing some reviewing, mostly in Triage. Until now I raised 299 flags, and 62 of them aged away (this is approximately 20%), which I think is quite a lot.

While I understand [why flags age away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287165/3959259), I'm wondering if a rate of 20% is common or if I'm doing something wrong when reviewing.

Comment: The number depends whether you flag to close in high-traffic tag or low-traffic tag, in low-traffic tag unforntuantly many of them will age away as will also the few close votes.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/365279/tags-with-many-expired-close-votes-last-90-days shows some tags with up to 97% expire rate -- they could definitely benefit from more reviewers.  In case it's not obvious, you can usefully restrict the review to just a set of tags you are familiar with.

Comment: I have 1609 aged away flags, out of  6710 - So it's common for a lot of flags to age away, often there's just too much crap being posted on this site for everything to be handled in time.

Comment: For reference, 285/1094 = 26% of my flags have also aged away, mainly from triage as well before I got the vote to close privilege.

Comment: I wonder what the rationale for aging of flags was? It's not like bad content ages away too and gets better over time. The close vote queue length would be a bit higher, but who cares about that anyway, just show 1k+ if there are more than 1k questions in the review queue and nobody needs to know how many there are exactly.

Comment: As a frequenter of the JavaScript tag, I *wish* my 'aged away' was *only* 20%... I'd imagine the rate is worse in language tags the get crappier questions like JS and PHP.

Comment: The aged-away ratio depends also on the types of flags you raise. For example (if i'm not mistaken) comment flags can't age-away, and some types of post flags can't (or won't) age-away either.

Comment: 79/208 , ≈38% , of my flags aged away :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, you're not doing anything wrong. If you mark a question as <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd>, it ends up in the [Close Votes review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats). At the moment of writing, its size is 9.4k and not nearly enough reviews are done to keep it small. After a couple of days with no action, the question you flagged will be removed from the review queue and the flag ages away.

As mentioned in [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287211/4751173), please keep on reviewing and look at it from the positive side: 80% of the flags were acted upon (though that could also mean just a single close voter agreed with you, in which case the question still won't be closed).

Comment: Doesn't the question actually have to be closed in order for the flag to count as helpful?

Comment: @NathanOliver it either needs to be closed, or at least one of the close voters cast a vote with the same reason as yours.

Comment: @NathanOliver close flags are validated as long as someone casts a single close vote after you flagged the question.

Comment: @Braiam not if the close voter selects a *different* reason than you. I recently had a discussion with a ♦ mod about this. Let me see if I can find the reference.

Comment: @Glorfindel nope. Any *close vote* while the *close flag* is active validates the flag.

Comment: @Braiam see [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253836/295232) by animuson♦: *Your flag gets marked as helpful if the question gets closed or if a user with full vote-to-close privileges casts a close vote for the same reason as you while your flag is still pending.*

Comment: @Braiam also, [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333899/how-is-it-possible-for-a-moderator-to-decline-a-should-be-closed-flag/333901#333901) is a more recent example, the one I could remember earlier today. Apparently, I can't remember my own user ID or I would have found it sooner in SEDE.

Comment: It really doesn't help that the max daily review count is 20. Doesn't help the queue sizes any.

Comment: @Qix for Close Votes, it's 40.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, having large amounts of aged away flags is all too common.

I am happy you brought up this question though, since it lends light to a problem with the closed votes queue. As @Glorfindel points amount, a large portion of these aged flags come from flags that were sitting too long in the closed votes queue. The amount of items in that queue is simply too great for the limited amount of people who have access to that queue to handle. One possible solution would be to open the queue to more reviewers by *slightly* lowering the requirements to access this queue.

Comment: Actually, the problem isn't so much that the pool of users that can review it is too small... There are enough of people that could. The issue is that not enough users in that pool are actually doing it. [See also here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/1743880)

Comment: @Tunaki That can be true too. This was just the first idea that came to mind. At least we agree on the main point which is, there is a problem of too many items in some queues which is leading to too many aged flags.