# Why do all my duplicate flags age out?

Tags: discussion

[Almost all of my "aged away" flags are "possible duplicates".](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1079075?group=1&status=5) Screenshot below, because only mods can see flags:
[image: aged_away_flags]

I am making these flags incorrectly? I think their purpose is to keep the site clean, so people don't spend time visiting similar questions and also so that only one question needs to be kept up to date. Am I misunderstanding their purpose? Is there any way that I can help to make sure they are addressed?

Comment: Only mods can see your flag history. But in general, the close queue is overloaded, so aging away doesn't mean there was anything wrong with your flag, it just didn't attract enough attention in time to be part of the fraction of close reviews that are concluded properly.

Comment: Aside: Which tag do you usually flag (as duplicates) in?

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing Seanny, but now that I know there are too many of these flags no wonder why my flag of a camouflaged duplicate hasn't been handled yet (one needs to read the entire question to see it's a duplicate).

Comment: @BhargavRao Python mostly, since it's the language I work with every day.

Comment: @Seanny123 Hmm, Don't worry. It won't happen again. I'm spending 3-4 hrs every day in the close queue searching for dupes http://i.stack.imgur.com/iAcc2.png. :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335820/how-many-aged-away-flags-are-common/335834#335834

Comment: Don't want to sound mean, but it's almost like tough luck. Aged away flags are a bit of an issue, especially with closure flags - the majority of my closure flags are aged away too :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're perfectly understanding the purpose of duplicate flags and by all means keep doing that. One day we'll find enough close voters to effectively handle all those flags and votes.

When you flag for a duplicate a review task is created. This task goes into the Close Vote Queue, that was [once filled with over 150K review tasks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252572/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut) waiting for a reviewer. As less and less people seem to be wanting to wade through that queue [some measures are now in place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions) to keep that queue around 10K. That is still a lot and we simply lack the voters to ever clear that queue and have a guaranteed handling of your flag.

If you have a clear enough duplicate that can be judged by others as well, feel free to bring it up the few chatrooms that accept cv-pls requests, for example the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room (read our [FAQ](http://socvr.org/)). The regulars there handle new /fresh / recent posts that need some kind of moderation. With 5 close votes the dupe is confirmed.

An alternative is to invite Gold Dupe hammers to opt-in on a tag monitored by [Queen](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33366273#33366273). When you flag a question that is monitored as a possible duplicate, the bot will detect the comment that is left under the question and then ping the users with dupe hammers. That is the shortest route to instant closing.

Or, if you find this to complex, get yourself a [Gold tag badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers/254590#254590) so you can dupe hammer all by yourself ;)

Comment: As the OP has called out Python specifically, I would also like to mention that the [python](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python) room does accept [close vote requests](http://sopython.com/wiki/cv-pls) for duplicate posts.