# Statistics on how many flags age away?

Tags: discussion, flags, statistics

Can someone help me get statistics about how many flags age away in general, per user, per data?

We have a question about [How many aged away flags are common?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335820/how-many-aged-away-flags-are-common), but the answer doesn't have any data. Also, seems we still doesn't have a statistics about how this is spread in SO and not on a user case.

The motivation is to understand if we really have a problem with flags aging away and, if it is real, what is its size. 
Also how this appear to users who flag. So statistics per "flagging user" would be of help.

It is based in gnat's suggestion in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373990/efficiency-of-review-queues-too-many-aged-away-flags?cb=1#comment629854_373990) in this other [recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373990/efficiency-of-review-queues-too-many-aged-away-flags?cb=1)

Comment: I believe the proper answer is "too many".

Comment: @StephenLeppik So... more than 0%?

Comment: FWIW, before I gained the ability to VTC, most of my aged away flags seemed to come from flags I raised in review. If I flagged something I saw on the New Questions page, it was usually marked Helpful pretty quickly, unless the flag was, like, totally misguided. This leads me to believe that it's probably the Close Votes queue and its infamously huge size that makes flags age away. If there are enough close voters looking at it right then and there, it'll get handed before flags age.

Comment: 1,440 helpful vs 395 aged away.

Comment: 3,311 helpful vs 56 aged away, so ~1.7%. I may be an exception here though.

Comment: 53 helpful and 15 aged away. 29 in review where 90% that would probably age away too

Comment: 3580 helpful 56 aged away. Most of the helpful flags are custom mod flags however and they can't age away.

Comment: 3739 helpful and 209 aged away, so that's roughly ~5.6 percent of aged away flags. I may be in the same boat as @Filnor

Comment: 122 flagged and 38 aged away, so 31% aged away. I spend a lot of time in review queues and am pretty new to the site (~1yr) so may be an exception.

Comment: I'm flagging since August. Right now ~20% (80 aged away to 410 not waiting - including 3 retracted).

Comment: 775 non pending flags of which 135 are aged away (~17.5%)

Comment: @Filnor Watching for NAAs and bad comments like in SOBotics will most likely make your age-away rate go down. The more you use it, the stronger the effect I would guess. For instance, I'm at 10,625 helpful (8,106 of which are "post flags") vs. 33 aged away. The ratio would be much higher if we only looked at closure flags.

Comment: ~800 total flags, 480 helpful, and 264 aged away.  
For whatever it's worth, I don't have VTC permission and most of my flags come from the review queue.

Comment: 565 helpful vs 202 aged away (~36%)

Comment: 880 helpful, 511 aged away (mostly from reviews)

Comment: 181 helpful, 74 aged away.

Comment: 2111 helpful flags, **zero** aged away. But I've had the vote-to close privilege for years.  Ask me how many of *those* have aged away.

Comment: I have 4322 flags, of which 4153 marked helpful, and 35 aged away (only post flags have aged away). The rest are pending, disputed, declined, or retracted.