# Why was my flag declined without giving a reason?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45606629/3959259) as off topic. The flag has been declined but no reason for why it was declined was given:

[image]

While my flag most certainly was wrong and deserved to be declined, I'm wondering why was there no reason given?

Comment: Good question. I just cast the final close vote for too broad on it.

Comment: I think it was because it got enough "Leave Open" votes in review to kick it out of the [close vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16990571)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is it possible for a moderator to decline a "should be closed" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333899/how-is-it-possible-for-a-moderator-to-decline-a-should-be-closed-flag).  While the question is slightly different, the answer does explain the problem.  This is also relavant from MSE: [What causes a recommend closure flag to be marked disputed, versus helpful or declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253827/what-causes-a-recommend-closure-flag-to-be-marked-disputed-versus-helpful-or-de)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Should 4x close and 3x leave open really auto decline a flag? Seems asinine

Comment: @Magisch didn't say I agreed with it, just that is what happened

Comment: Umm...speaking of disagreeing...I disagree with the "too broad" close reason there. "Off topic" would be defensible, but that question is not broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When moderators decline a flag, it gets a reason to go along with it. So yes, this is the telltale sign of a flag that was declined by the community ([Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1), actually, which is technically kinda-sorta a moderator, but stop picking nits!).

In fact, for "needs to be closed" flags, [the *only* way a flag is processed is automatically via the close-vote review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253827/what-causes-a-recommend-closure-flag-to-be-marked-disputed-versus-helpful-or-de).

psubsee2003 already found [the relevant review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/16990571). Your "needs to be closed" flag put the question into the close-vote review queue, and it received three "Leave Open" votes by community reviewers, so your flag was automatically marked "declined".

No, I have no idea why a 3 vs. 4 split on "Leave Open" vs. "Close" would result in a "declined" resolution status instead of a "disputed" resolution status. But that's how it works. There's no path for a "needs to be closed" flag to get "disputed" via the close vote review queue.

Comment: I think this is a badly designed feature.  Split decisions should at least be disputed, not declined.  Might be a feature request, if someone want to write it up

Comment: Wait, a feature request that the review queues are broken? That would be a novel idea, I doubt anyone's ever created one of those before.

Comment: Three leave opens overrode four closure votes?  Also, it's definitely off topic--asking *why* that company has/hasn't implemented something... and guess what!  You can reopen and close with the appropriate reason!  You're modrater, a monkey who has guns in youre hand!  Go use it!

Comment: Oh, by the way, I kept the message # to the mod message where the mods = monkeys with guns meme came from--enjoy!  it's #181

Comment: @Will It just occurred to me that I can manipulate the numbers in that link. Mind blown. Also, thanks for the link to that one. The replies never fail to disappoint.